# Subscribing to a message type regardless of the topic name

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to subscribe to all messages of a given type without knowing their topic names? It would be perfect, if the callback function could additionally see the related topic name.

My application: I would like to write a node, which is supposed to do some administrative work and therefor collects all [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) messages from every camera on my robot. But I don't know how many cameras my robot has.

This [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/56168/subscribing-to-multiple-topics-of-the-same-type/) comes close to what I need, but I'd still have to maintain a list of all my cameras separately.
Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260633/subscribing-to-a-message-type-regardless-of-the-topic-name/) by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 775 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could probably use the [Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) to get a list of all publishers for a particular message type (`getTopicTypes(..)`). Then iterate over that and subscribe to the topics that you're interested in.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-05-01**:
Thanks for the hint. That looks good.